# Case Statement in Oracle with multiple True expressions

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got a situation where I have more than one expression as True and I need to return all of them within the same colum defined in my report.

I tried applying a case statement or nested case statement but I only see one result since case statement is only picking up the first true expression.

How can I add multiple Case statement to retrieve all true conditions ?

** Extract Example from PL/SQL:**

```
SELECT CRN, CASE 
WHEN CASE_1 = 'A' AND CASE_2 = 'B' 
THEN FORMULA1 -- FORMULA1 is an output of a query
WHEN CASE_1 = 'A' AND CASE_2 = 'C'
THEN FORMULA2 -- FORMULA2 is an output of a query
WHEN CASE_3 THEN FORMULA3 -- FORMULA3 is an output of a query
END AS INV

FROM ACC;
```

1. Formula1 output: 100
2. Formula2 output: 500
3. Formula3 output: 400

What I'm getting:

| CRN | INV |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 100 |

What I'm expecting:

| CRN | INV |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 100 |
| USD | 500 |
| USD | 400 |

Example of Nested case used:

```
    CASE
       WHEN CASE_1 = 'A' THEN (
CASE WHEN CASE_2 = 'B' THEN FORMULA1
END)

 WHEN CASE_1 = 'A' THEN (
CASE WHEN CASE_2 = 'C' THEN FORMULA1
END)
END AS INV;
```

This also returns one result only.

Comment: thanks. Not sure how union will be used in my case. The case statement I'm using is in the middle of a PL/SQL which I'm applying to one field only. I think I'm using the wrong syntax in my example and once I adjust it I can get the right result back

Answer (score 2):

Building on @SadlyFullStack's comment I suggest this statement

```sql
SELECT CRN, FORMULA1 AS INV FROM ACC WHERE CASE_1 = 'A' AND CASE_2 = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT CRN, FORMULA2 AS INV FROM ACC WHERE CASE_1 = 'A' AND CASE_2 = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT CRN, FORMULA3 AS INV FROM ACC WHERE CASE_3
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. Formula1 & formula2 are not coming from ACC table as I have stated in my example. Not sure how union can be used in my case since this case statement is in the middle of a select query. I also have another union in place. The example i shared is an extract of of  long PL/SQL only

Comment: For the union it doesn't matter where the values come from, as long as they are the same number and type it will work, you can union apples and horses, to oracle they are both varchars.

Comment: What I need is to use a nested case statement to return multiple true conditions back and not a union all. The example above is wrong in my case and won't work for me as I have to use a case statement to select multiple conditions. I'm trying to find the right syntax for it

Comment: @SadlyFullStack, not sure I understood your question but in my case each row will be unique as shown in the expected output

Comment: A CASE expression always returns one value. What you must do is to make three copies of your original SELECT statement containing the CASE expression and union them. Each copy must then have one of the conditions from the original CASE WHEN in WHERE part. There is no reason why this should not work.